# Replace Xcode's Navigation template UITableViewController with a UIViewController and UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uitableview

Is there any simple way to replace a UITableViewController from Xcode's "Navigation based application" with Core Data with a UIViewController containing a UITableView? 
I'm looking to add things that the normal UITableViewController can't have, so I replaced it with a UIViewController, but my problem is that whenever I do replace the UIViewController containing a UITableView, I cannot getting editing and table reloading to work correctly. 
Does anyone have any tips or tutorials you can hand off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implemented the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [datasource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods?

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. I forgot to linked them in interface builder.